# How can I get the values of a Collection generated by IEnumerable in an Array or List?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, collections, interface

Sorry I have some code that has the function to generate a ListView -> grid from a csv file which is working correctly, my problem would be that I need to get the values of the columns in this case (Directory, Name, Event, Type, etc) and save them in an array or list type structure to be able to be treated with Linq queries and generate another type of view / graph. I have tried many things but I have not been able to extract the values from the Person class.
As a bonus I am using WPF.

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Directorio { get; set; }
        public string Nombre { get; set; }
        public string Evento { get; set; }
        public string Tipo { get; set; }
        public string Tamaño { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public Person(string directorio, string nombre, string evento, string tipo, string tamaño, string time, string path)
        {
            Directorio = directorio;
            Nombre = nombre;
            Evento = evento;
            Tipo = tipo;
            Tamaño = tamaño;
            Time = time;
            Path = path;
        }
    }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public IEnumerable<Person> ReadCSV(string fileName)
        {
            
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(System.IO.Path.ChangeExtension(fileName, ".csv"));
            return lines.Select(line =>
            {
                string[] data = line.Split(',');             
                return new Person(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4], data[5], data[6]) ;
             
            });
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ListViewPeople.ItemsSource = ReadCSV(@"D:\dato.csv");
          
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please be more specific with your concrete problem. You get an  IEnumerable<Person> so you should have everything you need.

Comment: The call to ChangeExtension seems useless.

Comment: this is a common misconception. Your data and display of the data are entirely 2 different things and should be treated also this way! don't try to extract any values from the display (in your case ListView) use always the underlying data, for filtering or data extraction. and separate the 2!

Comment: first step would be to hold the data that you read from the file into a separate collection. meaning an extra variable on class level. the second step would be here to create an extra class that does the loading and the data storage. don't do this in the `MainWindow`. Buzzwords here is separation of concern and single responsibility principle

Comment: Show your XAML code.

Comment: @Ralf I only added the listView so that you can understand what was the main purpose of the code, the doubt I have is how I can extract the values of the collection in an array since I was doing queries inside public `IEnumerable<Person> ReadCSV(string fileName)` where I get the result I wanted but it is not visible for mainWindows.

Comment: @MongZhu In principle that is my idea, but I want to make a function that generates a graph with values obtained from Person but I would not know how to do it since I need an array, inside `IEnumerable<Person> ReadCSV(string fileName) ` I could do what I wanted with queries and others but the data was not visible to the outside of the IEnumerable since the code of the graph is in mainWindow.

Comment: " but I want to make a function that generates a graph with values obtained from Person but I would not know how to do it since I need an array," why do you need an array? and with what should the array be filled? "but the data was not visible to the outside of the IEnumerable since the code of the graph is in mainWindow" I don't really understand. If you filter the stored collection of data that you read from file then you can pass this result to the mainWindow. Or even better to a viewmodel which will be bound to certain parts of your GUI

Comment: @MongZhu sorry how could you pass the results to mainWindow.

Comment: You wrote (I assume) `ReadCSV` to return an `IEnumerable`. If you wanted to return a `List` add `ToList()` to the `return` statement. If you wanted to return an `Person[]` add `ToArray()` to the `return` statement. But an array is almost never the right choice in C#. First you need to understand (and be able to explain) why you think you need a collection instead of an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: ok [here is a mvvm tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/wpf/example/992/basic-mvvm-example-using-wpf-and-csharp) please read this. Your questions are getting to broad for answering here on SP.